# How do apps like Dropbox, TeamViewer, RDP apps reach the computers they are installed on?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, p2p

I know (guess) it's some sort of centralized peer-to-peer connection going on there. But then, how it's established? The apps themselves act as clients and servers. They connect to some central server, populate the user's node with data such as IPs MAC addresses and rest. But then what?

1. Do they establish a direct socket connection between the user computers? If yes, how they avoid the routers?
2. Do they transfer the data through the central server?

The reason why I ask is that I wanna build a Remote Desktop application that will be able to stream the screen view in real time to the connected client app(s). I know there a tons of them out there, but 99% are slow. I know it's possible to be close to realtime, OnLive does it. The 2 RDCs that work with speeds close to realtime are LogMeIn Pro (which I don't want to pay for, because I need only HD stream fromt the paid package) and Radmin (which is windows-only).

I'm ready to code it (in C/C++/Objective-C), but I just don't know how to design the thing.

Comment: For one possibility you might like to read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

Comment: And you have already written a screen mirroring driver, haven't you?

Comment: "TeamViewer uses one of the servers of TeamViewer.com to start the connection and the routing of traffic between the local client and the remote host machine. The software then determines how to establish a connection. In 70% of the cases after the handshake a direct connection via UDP or TCP is established, the other connections are routed through TeamViewer GmbH's router network (via TCP or http-tunneling)." (Your friend Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer)

Comment: Thanks guys,  will read that one.

Comment: @Eugene, i will try to avoid building a house by starting with roof.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov Eugene's asking you about the foundation. Capturing and compressing the screen image is the hard part, and will have more of an impact on latency than any other factor, even the networking protocol.

Comment: Thanks @SeanD. for clarifying. However, the only problem I see with that (yes, I'm jr dev yet) is screen capture itself. I have a bit of experience with visual data streams compression. Yes, I'm aware of the amount of work ahead, but I still will do this just for education sake.

Comment: Just FYI, port forwarding plus peer-to-peer standard VNC works without very much latency. I don't know why all those remote desktop applications are so laggy.